# Unexpected requirement of "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, runtime-configuration

Recent changes in my Visual Studio solution for an ASP.NET Core (.NET 6.0) API application have resulted in a requirement for `"Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App"`, with the framework entry being added to the `.runtimeconfig.json` file and I cannot see why. This is an issue for server deployment.

The significant part of the changes was adding a new class library, referenced and consumed in the main web-app project.

The new `.runtimeconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.IsSupported": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

The web-app `.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="*" Version="*" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataStuff.SqlData\DataStuff.SqlData.csproj" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The new class library `DataStuff.SqlData.csproj`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Scripts\*.sql" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Scripts\*.sql" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The new class:

```cs
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataStuff.SqlData
{
    public class SqlSetup
    {
        public SqlSetup(string stringVal)
        {   //...
        }

        public async Task RunSetup()
        {   //...
        }
    }
}
```

`SqlSetup` is registered in the web-app services collection and called as a ["start-up task" in a `IHostedService`](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-3/)

```cs
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {   // ...
        await sqlSetup.RunSetup();
    }
```

As well as `SqlSetup.cs`, the `DataStuff.SqlData` project contains some embedded text files with SQL scripts. `SqlSetup.RunSetup` uses `SqlCommand` to run these scripts.

---

Investigation:

- I have looked through project dependencies and I can't find anything related to "Windows Desktop".
- I have tried stepping back to the previous revision/commit of the repo and re-implementing the changes

  - and `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` is not present the build output (also not present recent builds on build server, before the latest - where it is).
  - when adding the new `DataStuff.SqlData` class library back in again and consuming in the app, sure enough, `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` appears again.
  - just removing usage of the class library again, conveniently clears `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App`
- a fair bit of *googling*
- using some dependency/decompile tools to try find any clues
- The closest thing I can find relating to "desktop" are analyzers in the web-app project under `Dependencies` > `Analyzers`:

  - `System.Windows.Forms.Analyzers`
  - `System.Windows.Forms.Analyzers.CSharp`

I am not sure that the analyzers affect the build ouput directly. There doesn't seem to be a way to remove them - easily in VS at least. I was suspecting that they were there as they *potentially* could be of use due to the `windows` part of the project TFM, though the target has always been `net6.0-windows` - as this is the supported target for one important package - and this has never resulted in a `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` requirement in the past.

---

Any help in solving this will be appreciated. This could just be guidance on clearly tracking required runtimes from targets and dependencies.

Thanks.

Comment: may i know the reason behind setting `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>`  in `.csproj` file file? i would like to suggest you could try setting `net6.0`  this will remove the dependencies.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal We have a required internal package that only targets `net6.0-windows`. Are you suggesting that `-windows` is tied to windows desktop GUI functionality? From what I have read so far, it for OS sepecific APIs - nothing to tie it to .net "desktop" libraries specifically. We are pretty much only Windows server based at the moment, so Windows OS targeted assemblies are fine for the time being.

Comment: for further troubleshooting you could try running command `dotnet list package --include-transitive` to see a list of all the packages that your application and its dependencies are referencing. also for a test you could try setting `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>`

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Thanks, thats a usefull `dotnet` tool to get a full dependency list. `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>` still fails on build - as with just `net6.0` - due to that internal package I mentioned, requiring `net6.0-windows`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the extra `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` requirement in my `App.runtimeconfig.json` today as well. It turns out that happened after I updated `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` to 7.0.16, which was released only a few days earlier. Going back a version to 7.0.15 made the `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` requirement disappear.

It looks like `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` 7.0.16 brings in a few new packages that 7.0.15 does not. The dependencies are:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.16
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.4
>> Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.56.0
>>> Microsoft.Identity.Client.NativeInterop 0.13.8 [new]
>>> Microsoft.Web.WebView2 1.0.864.35 [new]
> Azure.Identity 1.10.3
>> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal 4.56.0
>>> System.IO.FIleSystem.AccessControl 5.0.0 [new]
```

In particular, it is interesting that the dependencies for [`Microsoft.Identity.Client` 4.56.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/4.56.0#dependencies-body-tab) are:

- For net6.0:

  - Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions (>= 6.22.0)
- For net6.0-windows7.0

  - Microsoft.Identity.Client.NativeInterop (>= 0.13.8)
  - Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions (>= 6.22.0)
  - Microsoft.Web.WebView2 (>= 1.0.864.35)

It so happens that I'm using `net6.0-windows` as the target framework too. So I'm guessing `Microsoft.Identity.Client.NativeInterop` or `Microsoft.Web.WebView2` must be the NuGet that's adding the `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` requirement, although I don't know how to confirm for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed breakdown. I also noticed `Microsoft.Web.WebView2` earlier today - I think the first real suspect for something that might require "desktop"/GUI functionality. Looking at some documentation, I got the impression that it wasnt necessarily tied to desktop apps and is supposed to support rendering that that can be used in other app types. However, your findings merited and brought focus on my continued investigation.

Comment: Looking closer at my package changes: I added `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.5` directly in the new class library - and upgraded references to match in the main app, replacing the version resolved for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.22`. So, while `net6.0-windows` was not required in the class library, it is in the main web-app, bringing the `Microsoft.Identity.Client` dependencies you listed. I tried stepping `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` back to `4.0.5` (EF Core dependecy in main app appears to resolve to `5.1.0`), re-built and success - `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` is gone.

Comment: A bit of google and I found: [**AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet** bug #4468](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/4468) - at least this is known and being worked on.